# How to fetch cell values from a grid view and store it in a variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i want to fetch cell values of a single row displayed in a grid view. This screen shot gives an idea of the problem.

[image: Grid view Showing details of a single person]

i want to store the name, mobile, email and course_interested in different variable here. 
any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the name of your gridview is `gridview1` (say), then you may do the following:

```
var name = gridview1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text;
var mobile = gridview1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text;
var email = gridview1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Text;
var courses_interested = gridview1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Text;
```

### EDIT:

If the databound item is `System.Data.DataTable`, then use the following:

```
var name = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
var mobile = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
var email = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
var courses_interested = dt.Rows[0][3].ToString();
```

Comment: dude i have already tried this code before. it doesn't work. although i have solved this problem by using query string. but i was hoping to do this way... thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: it would be better then to provide with some of your problematic codes to dig through. btw, good luck!

Comment: well i just wanted to get the cell values inside variables so i can insert those values in a table. and i wanted to do that using some way to fetch values from gridview. instead of using query string from the previous page.

Comment: have you bound that gridview to any datasource? like `System.Data.DataTable` or something else?

Comment: the problematic code is the same you've mentioned above ;)

Comment: see the `EDIT` portion in my answer, if it works, i would request you to accept the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to get each strings for each cells included in the single row. Once you have aqcuired those strings you can now assign a variable for each of them.
Here's how you can access the values once you have placed them in a variable:

```
    variable x = gridview.Rows[0]["ColumnNameOrIndex"];
```

Hope this was helpful!